# Close cmd after launching a server with batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, tomcat, cmd, maven-cargo

What Im trying to do is to close the cmd after running a cargo tomcat server through a batch script.. I've tried attempts such as;

- start mvn -P cargo.run && exit
- start "" mvn -P cargo.run
  exit
- start "" mvn -P cargo.run -Drepo.path=storage
  exit /b

none of them seems to work, and the cmd is still staying open. As seen in the SS.

Anyone who might know how it could be done?

[[image: ScreenShot]]

- OS windows 7

Comment: It looks like the app is waiting to be aborted, so the exit command never gets executed as the app is still running.

Comment: @LotPings: the `exit` doesn't even make it's way into the newly started instance and so will close the calling instance.

Comment: @Stephan Ack, but even if escaped the app will wait to be aborted.

Comment: Exactly, so there was actually two way of doing it, either doing it the way @Stephan suggested or by simply creating a new bat script that closes the cmd... found it waay to stupid to do, but Stephans suggestion did it :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what you try, is like `(start ... ) && exit`. You need `start (... & exit)` (logical notation, will not work like this).

You have to escape the `&` to be passed to the new instance:

```
start mvn -P cargo.run ^& exit
```

If you need `&&`, escape both of them:

```
start mvn -P cargo.run ^&^& exit
```

(`&` = "and then", `&&` = "if previous command was successful, then")